# Thymeleaf decorator is not working

Tags: spring-boot, decorator, thymeleaf

I created a new Spring-boot project and wanted to use Thymeleaf with the LayoutDialect. 
My pom.xml has following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>angular-ui-router</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I also have a @Configuration class where I add the dialact. And do the view resolving.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/projects").setViewName(
            "project/listProjects");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(
            "project/listProjects::content");
    registry.addViewController("/create").setViewName(
            "project/createProject::content");

}


@Bean
public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
    return new LayoutDialect();
}
```

}

I have one layout HTML which looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"> 
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div>header</div>
         <div  layout:fragment="content">
                <h1>Static content for prototyping purposes only</h1>

        <p>This is the layout of the site. The actual content will come
            from individual views making use of this layout</p>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

and an other HTML wich calls decorator on the layout html...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="layout/layout">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div th:fragment="content">
        <div>list....</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i run it as spring boot app I just see the content "list..."
The paths to the htmls are correct.
Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I also recognized, that when I used bootstrap stylesheets from the webjar the weren't loaded.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

see two errors here. first you need and space in the thymeleaf xmlns like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"> 
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div>header</div>
         <div  layout:fragment="content">
             <h1>Static content for prototyping purposes only</h1>
             <p>This is the layout of the site. The actual content will come
            from individual views making use of this layout</p>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

the second one has an error in

```
<div th:fragment="content">
    <div>list....</div>
</div>
```

it should be

```
<div layout:fragment="content">
    <div>list....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had the same issue. This answer worked for me. I my case, the missing xmlns:layout namespace was the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a lot of time with the problem that it does not work. A lot of examples on the internet say:

> **layout:*decorator*="layout"**

But the truth is that in reality

> **layout:*decorate*="layout"**